# SOLARIS + uname -v + OS version

Tags: linux, unix, solaris

when I type:

```
 uname -v
```

from where this command (uname -v) take the OS version ? from which file/configuration-files ?

Comment: which version of Solaris are you running ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Solaris, the `uname(2)` system call provides this information from the running kernel image. Your kernel image is likely at

```
/platform/`uname -m`/kernel/unix
```

or similar.

Where you can find old kernel images depends on how you upgraded your system. On newer versions of Solaris, if you have used Live Upgrade, `lustatus` will show you the available boot environments.

Answer (score 0):

`uname` get's it's information from the /proc filesystem, which is a representation of the currently running kernel.

Comment: Did you know which file under /proc have the previous OS version , I ask this because I upgrade my SOLARIS version and I need to know also the previous OS version , so how to identify this info ?

Comment: Normally it's in `/proc/version`

Comment: in SOLARIS I not have the file /proc/version

Comment: Sorry I'm drawing a blank in that case, although `uname -r` is more than reliable enough to determine which version you are running!

Comment: Usually uname(1) uses the uname(2) syscall; this is true in at least Linux and Solaris.

Comment: @SimonJGreen Solaris doesn't (ab)use the /proc filesystem in the same way Linux does. /proc is _only_ for information about running processes.